# Changes done to the style sheet are not visible

Tags: css

I am creating an online shopping cart website on XAMPP.

Sometimes, when I do some changes on the styling sheet they are not visible on the website. (Though the syntax of the name of the style sheet and the name of the path is correct and the same.)

But as soon as I rename the style sheet and give the new path of the link, the changes are visible on the website. This doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: cache issue may be. Try remove cache in such a case and retry

Comment: Thank you @Nitesh  I'll try to do it..

Comment: Try using `Ctrl+Shift+R`, this will hard reload the browser

Comment: As most people suggested it's browser cache. You can use some of the cache busting strategies https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement fingerprinting of your assets (CSS, JS, perhaps even images in case you often change them). As long as you're developing on your localhost, caching and clearing the cache is easy, but as soon as you get live users, you can't make them clear cache and the only way to propagate changes in assets (CSS, JS, images, fonts) to all users is via fingerprinting. How that is done, exactly, depends largely on your build process and your entire stack.
In essence, fingerprinting just adds a version query to your asset links. Eg., your CSS style won't be linked as style.css but it'll be linked as style.css?v=1 and then at next change, v=2, etc. Or it could have a random query based on last change timestamp or some other way.

Comment: Really helpful for future enhancements of the website.